# Zipping sub folders into separate zip files

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a directory structure like this:

    `Parent
    |->A
    |->B
    |->*`

and I need to zip it like so:

    `Dest
    |->A.zip
    |->B.zip
    |->*.zip`

Where the `*` means that I don't know what are the names of the sub-folders.

How can I do this?

I'm working with a maven project but I don't mind using the antrun plugin

Comment: Are À` and `B` modules of your parent `Parent`? What does the `*` mean  in particular `you don't know the names of the sub-folders` ? Are these folder sub modules or what?

Comment: There's no concept of modules in here just sub folders of in the file system. The set of subfolders is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that I like since it doesn't require antcontrib:

```xml
<target name="zipContentPackage">
    <basename property="dir.name" file="${file_name}"/>
    <echo message="Zipping folder: ${dir.name}"/>
    <zip destfile="${zip_dir}/${dir.name}.zip" basedir="${file_name}"/>
</target>

<target name="-wrapper-zipContentPackage">
    <antcall target="zipContentPackage" inheritAll="true">
        <param name="file_name" value="${basedir}" />
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="packageContent">
    <delete dir="${zip_dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${zip_dir}"/>

    <subant genericantfile="${ant.file}" target="-zipContentPackage" inheritall="true">
        <dirset dir="${content_dir}" includes="*" />
    </subant>
</target>
```

Notes:

1. I used [sagioto's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866088/zipping-sub-folders-into-separate-zip-files/23885657#23885657) to illustrate
2. This isn't the most efficient solution

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using foreach of antcontrib

```
<target name="init">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpathref="maven.compile.classpath"/>
</target>


<target name="packageContent" depends="init">
    <delete dir="${zip_dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${zip_dir}"/>
    <foreach target="zipContentPackage" param="file_name">
        <path>
            <dirset dir="${content_dir}" includes="*"/>
        </path>
    </foreach>
</target>

<target name="zipContentPackage">
    <basename property="dir.name" file="${file_name}"/>
    <echo message="Zipping folder: ${dir.name}"/>
    <zip destfile="${zip_dir}/${dir.name}.zip" basedir="${file_name}"/>
</target>
```